# How to access remote python kernel using VSCode / Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter, spyder, remote-server

I have a python installation within a virtual environment on an Ubuntu server 18.04. Within the virtual environment I have installed Spyder and iPython and Jupyter.

My requirement is: I need to open a local installation of VSCode or Spyder on a different computer (Windows / Mac / Linux) and run my codes on the virtual environment on the Ubuntu server.

A guide would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Please take at [our documentation](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/ipythonconsole.html#connect-to-an-external-kernel) to learn how to connect our console to a remote kernel.